# Istio: TLS info not found while sniffing

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have tested in mtls enabled cluster

Steps taken:

```
$ kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f samples/sleep/sleep.yaml)
$ kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f samples/httpbin/httpbin.yaml)
$ kubectl get pods  -o wide
httpbin-6547d9b48d-64mdc   2/2     Running   0          113m   10.244.48.251   ip-172-31-10-100.us-west-2.compute.internal   
sleep-7ff6f95948-g5vgf     2/2     Running   0          114m   10.244.74.100   ip-172-31-0-93.us-west-2.compute.internal  
$ kubectl sniff httpbin-6547d9b48d-64mdc -o dump-mtls6.txt
$ kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -c sleep -- curl -v httpbin:8000/status/418
```

Copied dump-mtls6.txt to wireshark. There is no info regarding TLS between pod 10.244.48.251 and
10.244.74.100

At line 33 we can see the message IM A TEAPOT. but there is no detail about TLSv1.2. How can I sniff TLS report?[image]

Comment: Hello, As far as I checked [here](https://blog.getambassador.io/verifying-service-mesh-tls-in-kubernetes-using-ksniff-and-wireshark-454b1e3f4dc9), it worked as designed. If you want to see tls you could try that what is mentioned in above tutorial, `You can do this by removing the “http” filter, and instead adding a display filter to only show TCP traffic with a destination IP address of your Pod and a target port of 20000, which you can see that the Envoy sidecar is listening on via the earlier issued kubectl describe command`. Could you try it and let me know if that worked?

Comment: There is nothing in port 20000